# Restored iOS 10 with broken Home button

Tags: iphone, ios, assistive-technology

I restarted my iPhone 6 running iOS 10 and the home button is broken, so I was using Assistive Touch. But at the first launch, Assistive Touch is disabled.
On iOS 10, we have to "Press home button to unlock". 
What can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a way to unlock an iPhone running iOS 10 that has a broken home button and no access to Assistive Touch. Try the following:

1. On your Lock Screen, swipe right.
2. You should see the Search field at the top.
3. Type Settings in the Search field.
4. Your 'top hit' should be the Settings app. Tap on this.
5. You should now get the Touch ID or Enter Passcode screen.
6. Enter your passcode.
7. You should now see your settings.
8. Go to General -> Accessibility -> Assistive Touch and turn it on.
9. Also, while your still in the Accessibility settings, scroll to and tap the Home Button setting
10. Change the Click Speed and/or Rest Finger to Open settings to see if that also helps.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for helping! On lock screen, I can't swipe to access to the research. I solved this issue with rebooting (again and again) my phone. :)
If you got a broken home button, I advice to don't upgrade to iOS 10

Comment: That's strange - swiping right anywhere on the iOS 10 lock screen should bring up the widgets screen with a Search field at the top. But I'm glad you sorted it out! :)

Comment: It wasn't the lock screen, it was the first launch screen (like a factory new phone).
http://ios-data-recover.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/ios_7_setup_new_iphone_howto1.jpg
Little bit like that, but on iOS 10, there is not swipe

Comment: I'm also interested in finding a solution. I reset my phone to factory settings and can't activate it anymore.

Comment: Just try to reboot it, connected to iTunes with USB, and restore your iPhone with iCloud or a local backup.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem. The fix is so simple. All you have to do is turn off your phone with the lock button and when it turns back on, it will be unlocked. Once you download your backup assistive touch will be reactivated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Shut down the phone
2. Turn it on (don't put it down, don't blink:). If the screen gets locked start from 1 again)
3. After the phone is setup go straight to configurations > general > accessibility > assistive touch > turn on
4. Optional - set only 1 icon to display and make it home

Answer (score 1):

My iPhone 6 got stuck on the "press home button to update". By using [this guide](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-ios-9.3.5-ipsw-for-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-direct-links/) and [this software](http://www.cydiaos.com/download-recboot/) I downgraded my phone to iOS 9 with works with a broken home button.

Comment: Didn't know it, seems good :)

Answer (score -1):

If you connect the phone to iTunes on a mac you can turn on VoiceOver from the Accessibility Settings there, then double-tap on text and tap again to enter it.

Idea from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303020/288316

Comment: wow, a downvote for an answer I used myself that works, with no explanation. why's that?