# How do you activate an iPhone with broken home button iOS 10

Tags: iphone, ios

My iPhone 5s had recently been cleaned of all files and data, including iCloud so I need to activate it. It prompts me to press the home button to activate but the home button on my iPhone doesn't work. Is there a way I can activate this phone without pressing the home button?

Answer (score 9):

You need to activate the accessibility function, Voice Over, on your phone.

1. Connect your iPhone, to a computer with iTunes installed.
2. In iTunes, select your device.
3. From the Summary pane, click Configure
   Accessibility in the Options section at the bottom.
4. Select the Voice Over and click OK.
5. Double tap on the Press home to
       open text.

Once you’re pass the activation, you can disable Voice Over. [More details on the fix](https://ngszekiat.com/activate-iphone-home-button-broken/).

Answer (score 2):

If you can't summon an on-screen home button, you can always perform activation on iTunes connected to USB.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate Assistive Touch to have a floating software button that will let you press the home button.

Go to Settings App > General > Accessibility > AssistiveTouch (slide switch to the right)

[image: assistive touch]

Comment: You can't do that if the home button isn't working in the first place. It's a catch-22

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Just power cycle your iPhone to get a different screen asking for language selection.

Edit:
To add a bit more detail, steps that worked for me:

- I plugged in USB.
- Pressed the power button.
- Slided to power off.
- Powered on again.

Then I could setup, starting by setting the language, to the point where I could add the AssistiveTouch button.

**Important:** Just make sure it does not go to sleep until then, because you would need to press the home button again