# Set up an iPhone 6 with non-working Home button

Tags: iphone

My brother recently gave me and iPhone 6 and he reset it before before handing it over. I turned it on and it says "Hello, Press home button to unlock and get started". But the Home button on the iPhone isn't working.

How can I get past this without replacing the Home button right now, and set it up with the Assistive Touch, until I get it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to access Assistive Touch until the device is done past the initial setup. The only way to get through the first step is to have a working Home button.

You'll have to get the Home button fixed before you can setup your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, this is easy.

You must have access to a mac and the right cable for your phone

With the phone at the setup welcome screen, you plug the phone in and iTunes should pop up. Open the Summary page for the device, and scroll to the Options section at the bottom. Select "Configure Accessibility", and turn on Voice Over.

Now you can double-tap on the "press home" text to voice-over-select it, then when you tap again, it enters it taking you to the next screen.

All the screens after the first one work without the home button so you can turn Voice Over off now and get to work.

Don't forget to turn on the Accessibility touch work-around from Settings as soon as you can! Good luck

Credit where it's due: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303020/288316 for [Scott](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/88535/scott)

Comment: wow, a downvote for an answer I used myself that works, with no explanation. why's that?

Comment: As the poster above, it worked for me as well. You have to first tap on the text ("Press Home...") and then double tap on top of it. That will just open the phone,  you can disable Voice over right after to enter all the info easier.