# Stuck on 'Press home to upgrade' with a broken home button

Tags: iphone, itunes

I had recently backed up my phone (iPhone 6+), and had to restore it since it was playing up, and when the phone turned on, I was greeted with the 'Press home to upgrade' screen. I had my assistive touch on the top of the screen, tried to press it but it didn't respond. I tried factory resetting it through iTunes, but iTunes requires me to input the password, which I can't really do. I can't put the phone into recovery, because as I previously mentioned, the home button is broken.

What can I do to get my phone back?

Comment: Why can't you input the password?

Comment: It's stuck on the 'Press home to upgrade screen', and unless you press the home button you can't input the password. In my case I can't get past said screen since the home button is broken and my assistive touch isn't working for some reason :/

Comment: See if this help: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/284345/119271. However, you need to get the button fixed - bodging things is good in a pinch, but you’re going to end up having issues as you progress